# Understanding Drawable.Callback, difference between invalidateDrawable and invalidate()

Tags: java, android, view, graphics, android-drawable

I'm using [StickerView](https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView) to add stickers to my app, now I'm trying to add GIF `drawable` as a sticker, the below code works, the `GifDrawable` is animated normally, but the issue here is each time the `Drawable` changes to the next frame, the entire `StickerView` is redrawn, over and over again, this consumes quite a bit of memory.

I tried to invalidate the drawable only using `stickerView.invalidateDrawable(who)`, but GifDrawable stops animating.

```
   GifDrawable gifDrawable = new GifDrawable(gifSticker.getBuffer());
   gifDrawableSticker.setGIF(true);
   gifDrawable.setCallback(new Drawable.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void invalidateDrawable(@NonNull Drawable who) {

                  stickerView.invalidate(); WORKING FINE
                //stickerView.invalidateDrawable(who); NOT WORKING

            }

            @Override
            public void scheduleDrawable(@NonNull Drawable who, @NonNull Runnable what, long when) {
                  stickerView.scheduleDrawable(who, what, when);
            }

            @Override
            public void unscheduleDrawable(@NonNull Drawable who, @NonNull Runnable what) {
                stickerView.unscheduleDrawable(who, what);
            }
        });
      stickerView.addSticker(new DrawableSticker(gifDrawable));
```

Comment: You can update a specific rect: stickerView.invalidate(who.getBounds());